# Showing that if $AB = I_m$, then columns of $B$ are independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$AB = I_m$, where $A$ has dimensions $m \times n$ and $B$ has dimensions $n \times m$.

I want to prove that the columns of $B$ are independent, but I'm not sure how.

$c_1 Ab_1 + \dots + c_mAb_m = (0,0, \dots 0)^t$.

We know that $c_1,\dots, c_m = 0$. So the columns of $AB$ are independent. This is where I'm stuck.

My attempt (which I think is wrong) is that $c_1 Ab_1 + \dots + c_mAb_m = A(c_1b_1 + \dots + c_mb_m).$ Since we know that the $c's$ are all 0 then $c_1b_1 + \dots + c_mb_m$ = zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where the $c_i, \dots c_m = 0$. So the columns of $B$ are independent.(This doesn't seem right because the zero vector is in different spaces, namely $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Suppose that $AB = I_m$ and that the columns of $B$ are not independent. Then, there exists a non-zero vector $c$ such that $Bc = 0$. Now, multiply both sides by $A$. Do you see the contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

Each row of $AB$ is a linear combination of the rows of $B$. If $AB=I_m$, its rows are linearly independent. Hence at least $m$ rows of $B$ are linearly independent, so that at least $m$ columns of $B$ are linearly independent. But $B$ has $m$ columns, which proves its columns are  linearly independent.

*Note:* in the same way, one proves the rows of $A$ are linearly independent too.

Answer (score 0):

we know that $rank(AB) = rank(I_m) = m.$ we also know that the row space of $AB$, which has rank $m$,  is a subspace of the row space of $B.$  therefore the dimension of the rowspace of $B$ is at least $m.$ it is exactly $m$ because $B$ has only $m$ columns. that is rank of $B$ is $m$ which in turn implies that the columns of $B$ are linearly independent.